Particles freezing when new script is called
I am experiencing a problem with a js console simulation application where the particle animation I made to fill an empty space freezes when I actually try to give the console something to work with. I have tried to search for solutions but could not find anything--couldn't find anything that had an explanation. I believe it might have something to do with the loop in parti.js being overridden but I'm not sure if that is the issue, and if it is, I'm not sure what the fix would be.


/* 
* START OF parti.js
*
*/
function createParticles(containerId, options) {
    const defaults = {
        particleSize: 8,
        particleSpacing: 100,
        attractionStrength: 0.01,
        attractionDistanceThreshold: 200,
        maxSpeed: 2,
        wrapAroundEdges: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        particleColor: '#ffffff',
        particleOpacity: 1
    };

    const settings = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
    const particleContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
    const particles = [];
    let mouseX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let mouseY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    // Set container styles
    particleContainer.style.backgroundColor = settings.backgroundColor;

    function createParticle(x, y) {
        const particle = {
            x,
            y,
            vx: 0,
            vy: 0,
            element: document.createElement('div')
        };
        particle.element.classList.add('particle');
        particle.element.style.width = `${settings.particleSize}px`;
        particle.element.style.height = `${settings.particleSize}px`;
        particle.element.style.backgroundColor = settings.particleColor;
        particle.element.style.opacity = settings.particleOpacity;
        particleContainer.appendChild(particle.element);
        return particle;
    }

    // Create particles
    for (let x = 0; x < window.innerWidth; x += settings.particleSpacing) {
        for (let y = 0; y < window.innerHeight; y += settings.particleSpacing) {
            particles.push(createParticle(x, y));
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
    });

    function updateParticles() {
        for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            const particle = particles[i];
            
            const dx = mouseX - particle.x;
            const dy = mouseY - particle.y;
            const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            
            // Check if the particle is within a certain distance from the mouse
            if (distance < settings.attractionDistanceThreshold) {
                const ax = settings.attractionStrength * dx / distance;
                const ay = settings.attractionStrength * dy / distance;
                
                particle.vx += ax;
                particle.vy += ay;
            }
            
            const speed = Math.sqrt(particle.vx * particle.vx + particle.vy * particle.vy);
            if (speed > settings.maxSpeed) {
                particle.vx = (particle.vx / speed) * settings.maxSpeed;
                particle.vy = (particle.vy / speed) * settings.maxSpeed;
            }

            particle.x += particle.vx;
            particle.y += particle.vy;

            if (settings.wrapAroundEdges) {
                if (particle.x < 0) particle.x = window.innerWidth;
                if (particle.x > window.innerWidth) particle.x = 0;
                if (particle.y < 0) particle.y = window.innerHeight;
                if (particle.y > window.innerHeight) particle.y = 0;
            }

            particle.element.style.transform = `translate(${particle.x}px, ${particle.y}px)`;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(updateParticles);
    }

    updateParticles();
}
/* 
* END OF parti.js
*
*/

let context = {};

function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

function log(message, type = 'log') {
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
    var messageClass = type === 'input' ? 'input-line' : (type === 'error' ? 'error-line' : 'result-line');
    consoleDiv.innerHTML += '<p class="' + messageClass + '">' + escapeHtml(message) + '</p>';
    consoleDiv.scrollTop = consoleDiv.scrollHeight;
}

function clearConsole() {
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
    consoleDiv.innerHTML = '';
    context = {};
}

function executeCode(input) {
    try {
        if (input.startsWith("log ")) {
            var variableName = input.substring(4).trim();
            log(variableName + ': ' + eval(variableName), 'result');
        } else {
            log('>> ' + input, 'input');
            var func = new Function('context', 'with(context) { return ' + input + '; }');
            var result = func(context);
            log('Result: ' + result, 'result');
    }   
    } catch (error) {
        log('Error: ' + error.message, 'error');
    }
}


document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        var value = this.value;
        executeCode(value);
        this.value = "";
    }
});

document.getElementById("clearBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearConsole();
});

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("focus", function() {
    document.getElementById('console').classList.add('console-focused');
});

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("blur", function() {
    document.getElementById('console').classList.remove('console-focused');
});

createParticles('particle-container', {
    particleSize: 2,
    particleSpacing: 100,
    attractionStrength: 0.01,
    attractionDistanceThreshold: Infinity,
    maxSpeed: 2,
    particleColor: '#e2e2e2',
    particleOpacity: 0.8
});
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.console {
    width: 90%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-family: monospace;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.console-focused {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}

.console .input-line {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}


.console .result-line {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.input-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.input {
    width: 84%;
    height: 5vh;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    outline: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.input:hover, .input:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}

.input::placeholder {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}


.clear-btn {
    height: 8.25vh;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: monospace;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.clear-btn:hover {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}

.console p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.console .input-line {
    color: #9cdcfe;
}

.console .result-line {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.console .error-line {
    color: #f48771;
}

.particle-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none;
}  

.particle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="icon" href="js.png">
  <title>JavaScript Console</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="console" class="console">
      <div id="particle-container" class="particle-container">           </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="input" class="input" placeholder=">">
      <button id="clearBtn" class="clear-btn">Clear</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




Have you considered making this a runnable code snippet (e.g. this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) to make it easier for people to see run your code and reproduce the problem?

I have recreated your code in a working snippit and it works without issue, no freezing, what would be an example of "give the console something to work with", also, if you'd like I can add a snippit to your question, just let me know.

@dalelandry an example of giving the 'console' to work with would be like typing into the input box at the bottom "hello world" or anything else and then pressing enter to submit it. the particles seem to freeze when that happens

My javascript became rusty, but I think the problem is in log function,
when it appends children to console via += to innerHTML, it probably messes around with event listeners and event-loop stuff.
function log(message, type = 'log') {
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
    var messageClass = type === 'input' ? 'input-line' : (type === 'error' ? 'error-line' : 'result-line');
    consoleDiv.innerHTML += '<p class="' + messageClass + '">' + escapeHtml(message) + '</p>';
    consoleDiv.scrollTop = consoleDiv.scrollHeight;
}

You can fix that by creating element via DOM API createElement and appendChild, like this:
function log(message, type = 'log') {
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
    var messageClass = type === 'input' ? 'input-line' : (type === 'error' ? 'error-line' : 'result-line');

    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.classList.add(messageClass);
    p.innerText = escapeHtml(message);
    consoleDiv.appendChild(p);
    consoleDiv.scrollTop = consoleDiv.scrollHeight;
}

It uses DOM API and therefore stuff is being handled properly.
Here is a working code snippet:


/* 
* START OF parti.js
*
*/
function createParticles(containerId, options) {
    const defaults = {
        particleSize: 8,
        particleSpacing: 100,
        attractionStrength: 0.01,
        attractionDistanceThreshold: 200,
        maxSpeed: 2,
        wrapAroundEdges: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        particleColor: '#ffffff',
        particleOpacity: 1
    };

    const settings = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
    const particleContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
    const particles = [];
    let mouseX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let mouseY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    // Set container styles
    particleContainer.style.backgroundColor = settings.backgroundColor;

    function createParticle(x, y) {
        const particle = {
            x,
            y,
            vx: 0,
            vy: 0,
            element: document.createElement('div')
        };
        particle.element.classList.add('particle');
        particle.element.style.width = `${settings.particleSize}px`;
        particle.element.style.height = `${settings.particleSize}px`;
        particle.element.style.backgroundColor = settings.particleColor;
        particle.element.style.opacity = settings.particleOpacity;
        particleContainer.appendChild(particle.element);
        return particle;
    }

    // Create particles
    for (let x = 0; x < window.innerWidth; x += settings.particleSpacing) {
        for (let y = 0; y < window.innerHeight; y += settings.particleSpacing) {
            particles.push(createParticle(x, y));
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
    });

    function updateParticles() {
        for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            const particle = particles[i];
            
            const dx = mouseX - particle.x;
            const dy = mouseY - particle.y;
            const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            
            // Check if the particle is within a certain distance from the mouse
            if (distance < settings.attractionDistanceThreshold) {
                const ax = settings.attractionStrength * dx / distance;
                const ay = settings.attractionStrength * dy / distance;
                
                particle.vx += ax;
                particle.vy += ay;
            }
            
            const speed = Math.sqrt(particle.vx * particle.vx + particle.vy * particle.vy);
            if (speed > settings.maxSpeed) {
                particle.vx = (particle.vx / speed) * settings.maxSpeed;
                particle.vy = (particle.vy / speed) * settings.maxSpeed;
            }

            particle.x += particle.vx;
            particle.y += particle.vy;

            if (settings.wrapAroundEdges) {
                if (particle.x < 0) particle.x = window.innerWidth;
                if (particle.x > window.innerWidth) particle.x = 0;
                if (particle.y < 0) particle.y = window.innerHeight;
                if (particle.y > window.innerHeight) particle.y = 0;
            }

            particle.element.style.transform = `translate(${particle.x}px, ${particle.y}px)`;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(updateParticles);
    }

    updateParticles();
}
/* 
* END OF parti.js
*
*/

let context = {};

function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

function log(message, type = 'log') {
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
    var messageClass = type === 'input' ? 'input-line' : (type === 'error' ? 'error-line' : 'result-line');

    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.classList.add(messageClass);
    p.innerText = escapeHtml(message);
    consoleDiv.appendChild(p);
    consoleDiv.scrollTop = consoleDiv.scrollHeight;
}

function clearConsole() {
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
    consoleDiv.innerHTML = '';
    context = {};
}

function executeCode(input) {
    try {
        if (input.startsWith("log ")) {
            var variableName = input.substring(4).trim();
            log(variableName + ': ' + eval(variableName), 'result');
        } else {
            log('>> ' + input, 'input');
            var func = new Function('context', 'with(context) { return ' + input + '; }');
            var result = func(context);
            log('Result: ' + result, 'result');
    }   
    } catch (error) {
        log('Error: ' + error.message, 'error');
    }
}


document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        var value = this.value;
        executeCode(value)
        this.value = "";
    }
});

document.getElementById("clearBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearConsole();
});

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("focus", function() {
    document.getElementById('console').classList.add('console-focused');
});

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("blur", function() {
    document.getElementById('console').classList.remove('console-focused');
});

createParticles('particle-container', {
    particleSize: 2,
    particleSpacing: 100,
    attractionStrength: 0.01,
    attractionDistanceThreshold: Infinity,
    maxSpeed: 2,
    particleColor: '#e2e2e2',
    particleOpacity: 0.8
});
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.console {
    width: 90%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-family: monospace;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.console-focused {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}

.console .input-line {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}


.console .result-line {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.input-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.input {
    width: 84%;
    height: 5vh;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    outline: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.input:hover, .input:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}

.input::placeholder {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}


.clear-btn {
    height: 8.25vh;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: monospace;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.clear-btn:hover {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}

.console p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.console .input-line {
    color: #9cdcfe;
}

.console .result-line {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.console .error-line {
    color: #f48771;
}

.particle-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none;
}  

.particle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="icon" href="js.png">
  <title>JavaScript Console</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="console" class="console">
      <div id="particle-container" class="particle-container">           </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="input" class="input" placeholder=">">
      <button id="clearBtn" class="clear-btn">Clear</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



